# Magento - How to restrict coupon codes to specific email id?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, newsletter, coupon-codes

I'm generating **Coupon** codes from shopping cart rules. And assigning coupon codes to **Newsletter subscribers**. But, the coupon code is getting used on any email address so, I would like to attach that coupon code to a specific email address only so that the coupon code won't work on other email addresses. Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

what all you can do is you can assign one customer to particular group  and select only that customer group for that coupon code.....

under Customer > Manage customer , assign that customer to **Wholesale group**

[image]

under shopping cart price rules , also assign that rule to **Wholesale group**

[image]

Don't assign any other customer to Wholesale group or you can create new customer group instead of Whoesale group....